# jQuery Flip! click events inside divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to make a flash card studying web app for a school project and I wanted to use [Flip!](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/) I have an issue, though when I put the anchors with their click events bound to the flip function inside the divs to be flipped. I am new to jQuery. Any help would be appreciated. Is there a flip forum? My code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Flippant</title>
  <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[    
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
    google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
    //]]>
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flip.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var f2b = function(){
    $("#card").flip({
      direction: 'tb',
      color: '#B34212',
      content: $('#back')
    });
  }

  var b2f = function(){
    $("#card").flip({
      direction: 'tb',
      color: '#B34212',
      content: $('#front')
    });
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip1").click(f2b);
    $("#flip2").click(b2f);
    $("#flip2").click();
  });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
  .back { display: none; }
  .front { display: none; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="card" id="card"></div>
  <div class="front" id="front">
    This is <br />
    the front <br />
    of the card. <br />
    <a href="#" id="flip1" title="flip to back">Flip1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="back" id="back">
    This is<br />
    the back<br />
    of the card.<br /> 
    <a href="#" id="flip2" title="flip to front">Flip2</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you have 2 click functions assigned to #flip2?

Comment: The 2nd one calls the click function set by the 1st one. The 2nd one is not assigning anything.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. What is it doing now, and what should it do? You just said "I have an issue."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the flip plugin destroys the event handlers that you set up on document ready. The way around it is to use [live event binding](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn). Change your document ready function to this:

```
$("#flip1").live('click', f2b);
$("#flip2").live('click', b2f);
$("#flip2").trigger('click');
```

**Edit:** I should also mention that the initial animation doesn't seem to fire unless you have specified a width in your CSS, like this:

```
.card { height: 200px; width:200px; }
```