# jQuery Flip! links inside divs

Tags: jquery, flip

Hey there. I want to use Flip (http://lab.smashup.it/flip/) for one of my projects. But I want the links to make the flip action inside the divs that are going to be flipped. I stumbled across a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482224/jquery-flip-click-events-inside-divs/2629199#2629199) and the reply was very helpful, and by using that codes I managed to achieve what I want. But now the issue is when the page first loads it automatically flips before clicking any link. I don't know much about jQuery. So I would appreciate any help.

Comment: could you please post your code so we can see what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are not calling trigger() or click() on document.ready

Answer (score 1):

If you're using exactly the same code from the question you've mentioned, the problem is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#flip1").click(f2b);
   $("#flip2").click(b2f);
   $("#flip2").click();
});
```

You're calling `.click` on `document.ready`